# how to get value from this php array

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array from json_decode

```
stdClass Object ( 
         [coord] => stdClass Object ( 
                             [lon] => 8.97 
                             [lat] => 51 
                            ) 
         [weather] => Array ( 
                          [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                               [id] => 804 
                               [main] => Clouds 
                               [description] => overcast clouds 
                               [icon] => 04d 
                             ) 
                         ) 
          [base] => stations 
          [main] => stdClass Object ( 
                        [temp] => 281.17 
                        [pressure] => 1014 
                        [humidity] => 87 
                        [temp_min] => 280.93 
                        [temp_max] => 281.48 
                       ) 
           [visibility] => 7000 
           [wind] => stdClass Object ( 
                        [speed] => 3.6 
                        [deg] => 180 
                      ) 
           [clouds] => stdClass Object ( 
                        [all] => 90 
                      ) 
           [dt] => 1445499854 
           [sys] => stdClass Object ( 
                        [type] => 1 
                        [id] => 4954 
                        [message] => 0.0056 
                        [country] => DE 
                        [sunrise] => 1445493535 
                        [sunset] => 1445530644 
                       ) 
            [id] => 2906244 
            [name] => Herbelhausen 
            [cod] => 200 
         )
```

i have get from it the description

```
$response_a2->weather[0]->description
```

but wen am trying to get the temp or pressure or humidity or speed i filed

```
$response_a2->base->temp
```

Comment: you should wrap your output in pre-tags so it is easier to view. as far as i see, your `temp` is located in `main`, wich means you can access it via `$response_a2->main->temp`

Comment: Now you can actually SEE the layout of the object _it should be quite obvious_

Comment: thank for the Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
$response_a2->main->temp
```

Thanks to **RiggsFolly** for beautifying the array.

next time, write your code like this:

```
echo "<pre">;
print_r($response_a2);
echo "</pre>";
```

and your array will look beautiful in the browser

Comment: My absolute pleasure

Comment: thank for the Answer

Answer (score 0):

That data does not exist in `$response_a2->base->temp`

Instead us

```
$response_a2->main->temp
$response_a2->main->presure
$response_a2->main->humidity
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing us is an object, not an array. Objects work differently from arrays. They use the `->` operator to reach certain values.

For example, imagine I've got object `$obj` and I wanna reach value `['some_value']`.

```
echo $obj->some_value;
```